# Dell xps screen shows nothing but is powered

Tags: 16.04, screen, xps

Dell XPS 13 running Ubuntu 16.04. On startup I can see the monitor getting powered up (changes from dark to dark with backlight) however nothing is happening/visible on the screen (no boot messages etc.) The laptop is starting up normally though, as I can login and will get confirmation sound. I can also attach a second monitor and it confirms the system works fine. If I activate both screens, the laptop screen will stay dark with backlight. I am using the intel graphics drivers.
How can I approach this?

This is the output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1200, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   3200x1800     59.98 +  47.99  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   1920x1200     59.95* 
   1920x1080     59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
DP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 518mm x 324mm
   1920x1200     59.95 +
   1920x1080     60.00* 
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And this is the output of sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log:

```
[  1614.872] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41082
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[  1614.873] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 41082
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "800x600"x0.0   40.00  800 840 968 1056  600 601 605 628 +hsync +vsync (37.9 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "640x480"x0.0   25.18  640 656 752 800  480 490 492 525 -hsync -vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "720x400"x0.0   28.32  720 738 846 900  400 412 414 449 -hsync +vsync (31.5 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1024x768"x0.0   65.00  1024 1048 1184 1344  768 771 777 806 -hsync -vsync (48.4 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x960"x0.0  108.00  1280 1376 1488 1800  960 961 964 1000 +hsync +vsync (60.0 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1280x1024"x0.0  108.00  1280 1328 1440 1688  1024 1025 1028 1066 +hsync +vsync (64.0 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1600x1200"x0.0  162.00  1600 1664 1856 2160  1200 1201 1204 1250 +hsync +vsync (75.0 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1680x1050"x0.0  119.00  1680 1728 1760 1840  1050 1053 1059 1080 +hsync -vsync (64.7 kHz e)
[  1663.155] (II) modeset(0): Modeline "1920x1080"x60.0  172.80  1920 2040 2248 2576  1080 1081 1084 1118 -hsync +vsync (67.1 kHz e)
```

Comment: You can reach tty console? Press Ctrl-Alt-F1, type and analyze `xrandr`and `sudo cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log`, maybe refresh rate is not suitable settled for monitor?

Comment: I have added the requested info. Not sure, if it gives us a hint? Thx in advance